# New name suggestion: Astronomy & Astrophysics

Tags: discussion

I had the idea that we could include Astrophysics in the name of this SE because it better reflects the nature of questions we receive. As well as being about observations of the sky (Astronomy) we also get asked many questions about the physical interactions of stars, galaxies, black holes etc (Astrophysics). I have nothing wrong with the title of the SE as it is but I thought adding Astrophysics not only sounds better but also is a better representation of this SE. Your thoughts and comments are most welcome and I encourage discussion.

Comment: Astrophysics is a branch of astronomy. It would be redundant to include it in the title.

Comment: I have no problems with the name as it is but I just thought it might help clarify what we talk about. Maybe there would be copyright issues with http://www.aanda.org/ if we changed it tho :P

Answer (score 4):

I would agree with this. Reasons above are good, and also if people are searching for information on astrophysics we want this site to be somewhere they visit even if they don't link the terms "astrophysics" and "astronomy" in their search.